# Is there a grammar rule for nouns coming from verbs?

Tags: verbs, nouns, orthography, doubled-consonants

I'd like to know if there is a grammar rule stating when the last consonant of the verb  has to be doubled. 
E.g. why: "to cut" -> cu**tt**er, "to program" -> progra**mm**er, but "to read" -> rea**d**er?

Comment: I personally have not come across any written rules regarding these word forms.

Comment: you double to prevent an unintended pronunciation.  Cuter rhymes with pewter.  Programer would rhyme with “pro gamer” etc.

Comment: I don't think this is a "grammar rule," more of a spelling or orthography rule.

Comment: The word was [*programme*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/programme) until the Americans shortened it. So clearly, the noun has to be *programmer*.

Answer (score 3):

The general rule is: double a single consonant letter following a single vowel letter with a short vowel sound; don't double anything else.  (The doubled consonant is a cue that the vowel sound should remain short.)

So:

- *cut* has a short 'u' and a single 't': therefore *cutter*.
- *program* has a short 'a' and a single 'm': *programmer*.
- *read* has a long 'e' sound from 'ea': *reader*
- *head* has a short 'e' sound but it comes from a double-vowel 'ea', so *header*.

Of course, this being English, there will be exceptions.

Comment: If you added _letter_ after _consonant_ and _vowel_ to parallel _short vowel sound_, the answer would be perfect. I recommend this because orthographic rules often conflate letters and sounds; they should be distinguished when stating the rules carefully. Since there are only 5 vowel letters to represent at least 14 vowel sounds in English, this is one of the dodges to make the vowel letters do double duty.

Comment: @JohnLawler tweaked as indicated.  :-)

Comment: Another important point to note is probably stress: the "short vowel sound" doubling rule doesn't apply with words like "edit, edited, editing" where the "i" corresponds to an unstressed vowel.